# Create a link which shows only a specific part of a wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I created some custom post types that include some advanced custom fields.

These are set up to include an event time, place — plus the guest of honor and his bio.

I'm packaging this all up into one post type so that the end user doesn't have to enter multiple posts — one for the bio, one for the event date, etc.

Most of the time, I want to show all the data about the event — time place, etc.

But sometimes I want to show only the bio of the guest.

So clicking link "a" will take you to a single post page which lists all of the information.

Clicking link "b" will take you to a DIFFERENT single post page which lists ONLY the bio.

I assume I would have to somehow create different templates which show this different data, or create a specific link which would direct to only the bio on its own page.

Any suggestions?

[Layout of What I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLFvV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you need two links per post to serve different layout, than you probably need two separate posts. For controlling the layout you can use a custom field so for example you can have custom field "layout" which can be "brief" or "full". You can indicate value from the back end of the post and in single-event.php template, you need to check if the post meta is brief, than show brief layout html, else if it is "full" then serve full html. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Not quite. I see what you're saying but I would really like to keep everything in one post. I did find a solution which was to add a query string to the end of the url, then check if that query string is present and display different layouts if the query string exists.       So I append ?bio=yes to the URL and my single.php checks for that string. Might be a little hacky but works for this. I'm sure there is another way tho

Comment: That is a good solution as well but if you need to hide some info from the user, he can easily alter the query string.

Comment: You're saying that someone could alter the string and it would reveal data I might want hidden? True, but I'm not trying to "hide" anything actually. They're just different views on the same data. I'm just trying to make less work on the backend for my end user

Comment: Then query string is what you need :)